# Rails Views: creating a menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, view, menu

I've run into kind of an odd issue. I'm showing a view where people can browse photos by different scopes, and I have the following menu in my view:

```
#photo_browser
    = link_to 'Recent', browse_photos_path(:view=>'recent'), :class => 'button'
    = link_to 'Best Photograhy', browse_photos_path(:view=>'best'), :class => 'button'
    = link_to 'Most Loved Places', browse_photos_path(:view=>'loved'), :class => 'button'
    = link_to 'Flagged', browse_photos_path(:view=>'flagged'), :class => 'button' if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_role?(:admin)
```

So, the currently selected view is a param in the url (ie.`photos/browse?view=recent`).
Now, I'd like to add a "selected" class to whatever link is the current view. The problem is I haven't been able to think of a good way to do this. I could do something like...

```
- @presenter.view == recent? recentClass = 'selected' : recentClass = nil
= link_to 'Recent', browse_photos_path(:view=>'recent'), :class => 'button ' + recentClass
```

...for each link, but that seems really verbose and kind of sloppy.

So, my question is, is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

Then, is it best for whatever code handles creating these menus to live in the view file, or in a helper, or in a Presenter model, or something else?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To do a similar thing before, I've used [Tabs on Rails](http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/tabs_on_rails/). Not sure if it will work well for query-params, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a helper method:

```
def browse_menu_button(name,view)
    @presenter.view == view ? btnClass = 'button selected' : btnClass = 'button'
    link_to name, browse_photos_path(:view=>view), :class => btnClass
end
```

Then in my view:

```
#photo_browser
  = browse_menu_button( 'Recent', :recent )
  = browse_menu_button( 'Best Photography', :best )
  = browse_menu_button( 'Most Loved Placed', :loved )
  = browse_menu_button( 'Flagged', :flagged ) if user_signed_in? && current_user.has_role?(:admin)
```

That ended up working about as efficiently as anything else I could come up with.